# Kendo file upload does not submit all uploaded files to controller for saving on IE11

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am using kendo file upload in our ASP.NET application(MVC4). It works fine on Firefox and Chrome. When I try to upload files on IE11, not all files are sent to controller for saving (I know this by printing out all file upload requests). And another observation is that it seems that kendo file control does not report Success event for those not-uploaded files(This is known by debugging javascript event handler). The following is the file upload code:

```
 <div>
        @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
              .Name("files")
              .ShowFileList(false)
              .Async(async => async
                  .Save("save", "Upload")
                  .AutoUpload(false)
                  .Remove("Remove", "Upload"))          
              .Events(events => events
                  .Progress("file.fileUploadOnProgress")
                  .Upload("file.fileUploadOnUpload")
                  .Select("file.fileUploadOnSelect")
                  .Success("file.fileUploadOnSuccess")
                  .Error("file.fileUploadOnError")
                  .Complete("file.fileUploadOnComplete")
                  .Cancel("file.fileUploadOnCancel")
              )
              )    
    </div>
```

My question would be is this a known issue for Kendo file upload control or an issue file upload control works with IE browser or it is an issue in my code? My guess would be if nobody has similar issue , it is probably my code problem and I probably need to revisit my code and find out the root cause. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days investigation, it looks like an IE bug.

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/819941/file-upload-stop-working-on-ie-with-windows-authentication#tabs